# Oozie Shell Action Issue

Tags: apache, bash, cloudera, oozie

I'm trying to implement a simple ls command through a shell action, but i'm facing an error,

**Exact Issue:**
*script:*

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /home/my-directory
```

*stdout logs:*

```
>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>
Exit code of the Shell command 2
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
Oozie Launcher ends
```

---

*stderr logs:*

```
ls: cannot access /home/my-directory: No such file or directory
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

There is a directory /home/my-directory and it also has sub-directories.

It will be great if anyone can provide me a solution to this.

Comment: Is /home/my-directory in the Hadoop file system, or the "real" file system? `ls` doesn't know about Hadoop.

Comment: That directory is in my linux filesystem.

Comment: did you get this resolved ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have control over which node in your cluster Oozie runs the shell action on. Therefore, your script should never reference the local file system of any particular node in your cluster.

E.g., say your cluster contains two nodes NODE1 and NODE2 and your script references a file that is on NODE1's FS. When Oozie runs your script, it can run it from either NODE1 or NODE2 (remember -- you put your script, job.properties, workflow.xml into HDFS, which is distributed across NODE1 and NODE2). If the script is run from NODE2, then you'll get the No such file or directory error because the file isn't present on the local FS of NODE2.

The important point is that any script you run via Oozie must only reference paths and files in HDFS. If you need a file from the FS local to one node to be referenced, put it in HDFS and use the path within HDFS to reference the file.